# ios - Core data - app crash if deleting before save finished

Tags: ios, core-data, asynchronous, crash, nested

My app simply add some users informations (name, birthdate, thumbnail, ...) with Core Data.

I noticed that if I delete a user right after created it, my app just stop working (not a crash, xCode returns no crash log, nothing).

I'm using asynchronous nested context for saving my users informations so I guess that behavior is due to the fact that my `delete` statement is executing before my `save` statement.

But since i'm a total beginner with Core Data, i don't really know how to handle that. I don't even know if i declared nested contexts the right way.

Here's my `save` codes :

```
NSManagedObjectContext *tmpContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    tmpContext.parentContext = self.backgroundManagedObjectContext;

    BSStudent *newStudent = (BSStudent *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:kBSStudent inManagedObjectContext:tmpContext];

    newStudent.firstname = firstname;
    newStudent.lastname = lastname;
    newStudent.birthdate = birthdate;
    newStudent.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    newStudent.createdAt = [NSDate date];

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    [tmpContext performBlock:^{
        [tmpContext save:nil];

        [self.backgroundManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            NSError *error;
            if (![self.backgroundManagedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }

            [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
                NSError *error;
                if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
            }];
        }];
    }];
```

For precision, `self.managedObjectContext` is a `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and `self.backgroundManagedObjectContext` is a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`. And `self.backgroundManagedObject` is a child of `self.managedObjectContext`.

Here's my delete codes :

```
    BSStudent *student = objc_getAssociatedObject(alertView, kDeleteStudentAlertAssociatedKey);

    // on supprimer l'objet et on sauvegarde le contexte
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:student];
    NSError *error;
    if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Can someone know how to handle this situation properly ?

Answer (score 4):

Your delete is probably using the `BSStudent` created by a different context than you are deleting with. The following code will fix that.

```
NSManagedObjectContext * deleteContext = student.managedObjectContext;
[deleteContext deleteObject:student];
```

If you really want to use the other context, refetch the student using ObjectID

```
NSManagedObject * studentToDelete = [self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:student.objectID];
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:studentToDelete];
```

### Nested contexts tips

Your contexts are probably okay, but I see a lot of people throwing around performBlock unnecessarily. With nested contexts, the QueueConcurrencyType refers to the thread it will do Core Data operations on, not the thread it was created on. So doing an operation like save on itself inside its performBlock is unnecessary and can lead to deadlocks.

When you save a child context, the parent is automatically synced with the changes. If you want to save upwards to the next higher parent automatically, I would recommend registering the parent for NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification of the child saves. You can make this easier by having your AppDelegate have a factory method for creating the child contexts.

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)createChildContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *tmpContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    tmpContext.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    //Register for NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
    return tmpContext;
}
```

Comment: Still not working with `NSManagedObjectContext * deleteContext = student.managedObjectContext;. For precision, delete is working if i wait a few second after the save. It crash only if i quickly delete a user right after created it. Concerning your "Nested contexts tips", i still don't fully understand how it work. Can you provide me the right way to code my save operation plz ?

Comment: When an app crashes with no exception, log, etc, it's usually a threading issue. Managed object contexts are not thread safe. So you are probably using a context on a thread different from the thread it was created on.

Answer (score 1):

if you wrap your delete in a `performBlock` call it can't execute at the same time as the saving `performBlock`.

e.g.:

```
BSStudent *student = objc_getAssociatedObject(alertView, kDeleteStudentAlertAssociatedKey);

// on supprimer l'objet et on sauvegarde le contexte
[self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:student];
    NSError *error;
    if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}];
```

This is the "preferred" way of dealing with contexts as it serializes access to the context and keeps all those operations on the contexts thread,

I assume you are getting the crash because the objectID is becoming invalid or changing before the save completes, near the top of the call stack you'll see something about "hash64" or such